# If i root my htc 0pcv1 will anything erase? Also how do i safely root my andriod?

Tags: rooting, htc

This is exactly what my device look like. I am rooting my device because I only have 4gb and I dont have space for apps and games I want.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMOBA.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

Rooting your Android does not erase data but it is recommended that you should take backup prior root, just in case you do not root properly which might lead to locking your motherboard.

Please note that

1) Rooting might void your phone's warranty.

2) You won't receive OS update through OTA.

3) If rooting is not done properly, your device becomes bricked.

Rooting has n number of advantages too, but please research thoroughly before doing it. [This article](http://www.androidcentral.com/root#H) might help you. Good luck :)

Comment: Ok wait... I'm 14 and I don't know how to root. I don't want to make a mistake.... I'm nervous. Is there a app that is free or a site that is 100% safe that will root. And will everything be normal? I dont access to things that are not made for me to have. All I want is more space. Google play services take up to much space.Thanks

Comment: There is no need to be nervous or anything, just research well before you root and you will be good.